# URL Rerouting failing on IIS 7 do i need to add any configuration to set it up?

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-4.0

URL Rerouting failing on IIS 7 do i need to add any configuration to set it up ?

I was previously using IIS 6 and did not specify any configuration settings. My app is built on asp.net 4.0. I tried to add the following config but still it failed.

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules>
<add name="RoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing,       Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </modules>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that you are running under IIS 7.0 Integrated mode. If you need to run it under IIS 7.0 Classic mode, you need to perform several actions to make the routes work. Please refer the following blog posts;

[http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/running-asp-net-mvc-under-iis-6-0-and-iis-7-0-classic-mode---solution-to-routing-problem](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/47)

[http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/deployment-of-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2-application-on-a-shared-hosting-environment-without-begging-the-hosting-company](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/39)